# How to print the first 5 names that are Males

Tags: java, sorting, if-statement

I have a list of name their gender and how many people have this name. 
My program prints out the names in descending order based on how many people have the same name. I am having with the Top function i am trying to create. it is suppose to take the the program and print the top 5 make in the list of names.

** List of Names**

Isabella F 22822

Jacob M 22011

Sophia F 20566

Ethan M 17956

Emma F 17277

Michael M 17244

Jayden M 17101

William M 16979

Olivia F 16959

Alexander M 16701

** What i am trying to get**

Jacob M 22011

Ethan M 17956

Michael M 17244

Jayden M 17101

William M 16979

** Got the sorting already figured just need hep printing first 5 males***

```
Top = top(5, M);

Collections.sort(oneName, new OneNameCountCompare());
for(OneName b: oneName) {
    System.out.println(Top.b.toString());
}

    }

String top(int many, char sex) {
    String order = "";
    for (sex = sex ; int i < many; i++) {
        order = i; 
    }
    return order;
}
```

Comment: Your code hurts my eyes.

Comment: Add a counter to keep track of how many names you have printed out so far. Stop when you reach 5.

Comment: I tried to reformat your code, but you seem to have some extraneous brackets. Please provide working code fragments.

Comment: That "if" statement is weird, it looks more like a "for" statement, but it isn't a valid "for" statement either. Please provide code that can at least be compiled before asking for help.

Comment: Please reformat your code.  Just because whitespace is "optional" does not mean you should litter your code with random amounts of it.  Well-written code has a consistent indentation scheme and does not contain extra blank lines.

Comment: How you have store the data ? means in class, List or else..

Answer (score 0):

When you invoke

```
Top = top(5, M);
```

Your code makes nothing close to what you want. You are passing `M` instead of `'M'` as a char. Unless you have defined `M` as a char somewhere, your code will not compile (your IDE will tell you that though).

After that, you are creating a String called `order`. Fair enough. But you for loop makes no sense at all. `sex = sex` has no effect at all (you are copying the content of `sex` into `sex`). Then I believe you are trying to loop over `i` `many` times. I'll give you the code that does that here, as I believe this might help:

```
for(int i=1; i<=many; i++){...}
```

And the next thing you do is copying an Integer into a String. I think you should go back to the basics and read the java basic tutorials. [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/index.html) is the link in case you are not sure what to look for. Spoiler: it going to be something like:

```
String.valueOf(i);
```

And finally you return `order`. I'll leave you to it to figure out what this is returning after you read the tutorial above.